# Trying to understand Blades, Racks, clusters in Azure

Tags: azure

Could anyone help me to understand blades, racks, clusters in azure and how they are related. Not sure from where to start.

Answer (score 1):

its a cloud platform. there are no blades,racks and clusters. there are resources. you dont care about underlying hardware.

only thing that matters - Fault and Upgrade domains. Read [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/manage-availability).